# Call a react component inside a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, export, ternary

There is an export functionality function which, based on an argument which says the type, exports the data in csv or xls format.

It works fine for xls but not for csv, here is the code:

```
  const exportFile = (exportType) => {
    exportType === 'csv' ? exportCSV() : exportXLS();
  };

  const exportXLS = () => {
    const sheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(computeExportFields(orders));
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, sheet, 'Sheet1');
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `MyFile.xls`);
  };

  const exportCSV = () => {
    return <CSVLink {...csvReport} />;
  };
```

so the problem must be in the last function, `exportCSV`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning JSX code from `exportCSV` function, it should only be in `render`. Try setting a state to check the exported type, something like:

```
const [type, setType] = useState();

const exportFile = (exportType) => {
  setType(exportType === 'csv' ? : 'xls');
};

return (
  {type === 'csv' ? <CSVLink {...csvReport} /> : exportXLS()}
);
```

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Must be the case.